# Python unittest: download the dataframe if the test failed

Tags: python, unit-testing

I want to be able to download the dataframe if a test was failed.

This class checks if a test is passed

```
import unittest
class TestPass:
    def is_equal(self, source, target):
        m = source.merge(target, on='id', how='outer')
        m['diff'] = m['cnt_x'] - m['cnt_y']
        if m.isnull().mean().max() == 0:
            return True
        else:
            m.to_csv(f'log/{self.TestCase.id()}')
            return False
```

the test class

```
test = TestPass()
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def dummy(self):
        df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'cnt': [2, 3, 6]})
        df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'z', 'c'], 'cnt': [2, 1, 6]})
        self.assertTrue(test.is_equal(df1, df2))
```

I'm not sure about how to get the current test's name and use it as the file name for download. My current code `m.to_csv(f'log/{self.TestCase.id()}')` doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `unittest.TestCase.id()` itself but in this way,

```
import unittest
class TestPass:
    def is_equal(self, source, target):
        m = source.merge(target, on='id', how='outer')
        m['diff'] = m['cnt_x'] - m['cnt_y']
        if m.isnull().mean().max() == 0:
            return True
        else:
            m.to_csv('log/'+self.TestCase.id()+'.csv')
            return False
```